# How do I implement the container view which represent the thumbnail of video having variable cell sizes?

Tags: cocoa, nscollectionview, ikimagebrowserview

i am developing cocoa application on mac os x, which will allows the user to import the video clips and make the movie from those video clips.here i need to deal with highly customized view....(please refer the attachment)...

my requirement is:

->>moment user add the video clip it will be added to the container view(which contains all the inserted video clips) and represent as a thumbnail.
->>each and every thumbnail item should have the different width based on the duration of the video clip(for example : if i consider the container view width is 120 pixel and make equal to 2 mins(120 sec)... then if user add the video clip which duration is 10sec then thumbnail width should be 10 pixel).. for that i needed the thumbnail item(cell) size should be variable at runtime based on the incoming video clips duration...
->>slider playloc functionality to see the progress while user play the main movie..

my approach:

->> i have created the NSView which is having IKImageBrowserView (thumnail container)and NSScrollView
->>and custom playloc button which is getting animated its position based on the progress value...

problem:
->>rightnow i am not able to set the cell size for each and every item differently...because it is a member function of IKImageBrowserView...

if i call [imageBrowser setCellSize:];then it applies to all the cells... not for a particular cell...

can any one suggest how to fix this problem..?

and is it possible to set the variable cell size for each and every cells in IKImageBrowserView?

what about the NSCollectionView? whether it is possible to set the different size for each and every cell in NSCollectionView?..

can anyone please help me to fix this problem....

Thanks & Regards,
Muthu

Answer (score 0):

it seems using NSCollectionView should be possible,

refer following link 
[Apple Example about How to use NSCollectonView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/IconCollection/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004477)
[Search for How do I change the size of the NSCollectionView subviews?](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSCollectionView)

Hopefully you would have read these two, if i get chance, i will play with it and will provide you example.

and this might also help [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627917/resize-view-of-nscollectionviewitem?rq=1)

Comment: i need the following functionalities:1.i need a List View which will allows the user to add the Thumbnail Image of the video clip with variable cell size(width will be varied based on the duration of the video clip)
2.remove the thumbnail cell 
3.select the thumbnail cell(selection will be highlighted)
4.reorder the items(Thumbnail Cells) in the ListView.i found the similar projects...1.PXListView (https://github.com/Perspx/PXListView)
2.SDListView (https://github.com/arbales/SDListView)
3.AMCollectionView(http://www.harmless.de/cocoa-code.php)....anyone suggest please which one is best?